# Webview Webpage not available ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have been working on an android application, using Kotlin. Recently, I have been trying to implement video calls using Javascript with the help of Webview in android, the problem is that when loading the activity in which the Webview is in, it does not show the HTML page.
As far as I know, everything is in place, and the code from what I've researched should be fine. I have already rebuilt the application and it still does not work.

That code box below shows the supposed correct way to load the page, but I only get a: "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

```
val filePath = "file:///android_asset/Content/call.html"
webView.loadUrl(filePath)
```

[image: Folder structure.]

[image: Webpage not available.]

Then I tried to access the page using the following syntax for the filepath:

```
val filePath = "./src/main/assets/Content/call.html"
```

And it worked, it stopped showing the error, but this is a problem, because it doesn't work like that on physical devices.

There is also this error that shows in logcat:

```
E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/Content/call.html
```

I have also tried moving the files outside of the Content folder, does not work.

This is perhaps a very simple mistake, but I can't find the solution. It would be highly appreciated if any of you could help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my specific problem.
It turns out that my "assets" folder was not inside the "main" folder, but inside a different folder in "src". I just created a new assets folder inside "main" and placed the files there, now the HTML page loads properly. Had to go into project view.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a WebViewAssetLoader. This is the android recommended way to load static webpages and you should not be using file path.

[WebviewAssetLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewAssetLoader) will host the files in the below path - http(s)://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/...

In your case it would be - https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/Content/call.html

Sample code :

```
final WebViewAssetLoader assetLoader = new WebViewAssetLoader.Builder()
          .addPathHandler("/assets/", new AssetsPathHandler(this))
          .build();

 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     @RequiresApi(21)
     public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                      WebResourceRequest request) {
         return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
     }

     @Override
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // for API < 21
     public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                                      WebResourceRequest request) {
         return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(Uri.parse(request));
     }
 });

 WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
 // Setting this off for security. Off by default for SDK versions >= 16.
 webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(false);
 // Off by default, deprecated for SDK versions >= 30.
 webViewSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(false);
 // Keeping these off is less critical but still a good idea, especially if your app is not
 // using file:// or content:// URLs.
 webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(false);
 webViewSettings.setAllowContentAccess(false);

 // Assets are hosted under http(s)://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/... .
 // If the application's assets are in the "main/assets" folder this will read the file
 // from "main/assets/www/index.html" and load it as if it were hosted on:
 // https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/www/index.html
 webview.loadUrl("https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/www/index.html");
```